# Load Azure PowerShell Cmdlets onto Remote VM

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, build-automation

I am using PowerShell to automate the creation of a virtual machine in Azure, then using Remote PowerShell to run commands on that machine.  I can run any PowerShell command that ships with Windows perfectly well, but when I try to run something like:

```
Set-AzureSubscription or Get-AzureStorageBlobContent
```

I get the following message:

*The term 'Set-AzureSubscription' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.*

Of course, because the Azure module is not preloaded on the VM in Azure.  Is it possible to copy the Azure Module up to the VM using PowerShell?  Or any other way to go about this assuming everything must be automated with PowerShell (so I can't log into the VM to run the Azure PowerShell installer or copy and paste over a remote desktop session)?

Answer (score 0):

Did use the Azure Powershell? If not you can install it here:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have Azure module installed

Try this to check:
Get-AzureModule Azure

You shoud get the module here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/#cmd-line-Tools